# Reuse a unittest method in another method under same test class

Tags: python-2.7, python-unittest

Lets say there is a testcase like this testing two features using unittest

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.something = X()
    def test_this(self):
        assert self.something.part1()
    def test_next(self):
        assert self.something.part2()
```

In the setUp the object will store self.something.

What if procedure test_next depends upon self.something.part1()?

How can self.something.part1() be reused in test_next?

I don't want to create stubs. I want to look for feature in unittest if it makes this possible and not go for mock.

Answer (score 1):

You shall not make your test cases inter-dependent. Either move the dependent stuff to `setUp`, or put it into non testing share method `prepare_something_part1` and call this from all related test cases, but do not mess up your test suite with interdependency which is difficult to maintain and use.

### Conclusion from our chat

Code reuse is good thing, test driven development too.

With test driven development it is essential to write test cases and code reuse (in test cases) is not so important.

Simply: relax, play with writing test case and code reuse in test cases will naturally come in soon.

Comment: You mean no scope for data flow driven test cases?

Comment: Quoting from Python doc for unittest: "When the test is run, the fixture initialization is run first; if it succeeds, the cleanup method is run after the test has been executed, regardless of the outcome of the test. Each instance of the TestCase will only be used to run a single test method, so a new fixture is created for each test." In short: each test_??? method gets setUp and tearDown called separately, no context across multiple tests.

Comment: For flow driven tests: `behave` package is what could serve you well. `nose` and possibly `unittest` might have module or package wide fixtures, which might allow live context across multiple tests.

Comment: I got that. But what if each test case has a code where lets say one Object assert Obj.step2  wasn't possible w/o Obj.step1?
Now that Obj.step 1 and 2 are in different testcases, how would step2 proceed if it doesn't have, say an attribute that is assigned some value only after step1 is executed?

Comment: @user2290820 In such case you have have to manage having Obj.step1 existnece before doing the next step. Do not be afraid form some code repetition in testing - it is quite common.

Comment: are you sure? of what ive seen from various advisors in this field, there are better ways to reuse code.if im repeating i must be doing wrong, is what i thought

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52128/discussion-between-jan-vlcinsky-and-user2290820)